# Appending child html after specific already appended child - jquery

Tags: jquery

Trivial question, but couldn't figure it out. Googled it a bit, but surprisingly didn't find a clear answer for my particular example.

I have got an html bit:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="box15"></div>
   <div id="box12"></div>
   <div id="box7"></div>
   <div id="box1"></div>
   <div id="box3"></div>
</div>
```

How would I append html bit `<div id="box19"></div>` to `main` id after specific child, for example after `<div id="box12"></div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**.insertAfter()**](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

*Code*

```
$('<div id="box19">box19</div>').insertAfter("#box12");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vTWyY/)

***OR***

You can use [**.after()**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$("#box12").after('<div id="box19">box19</div>' );
```

[**DEMO with after**](http://jsfiddle.net/ueAYh/)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
$('<div id="box19"></div>').insertAfter("div#box12")
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vTWyY/2/)

Answer (score 0):

var div = document.getElementById('main');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '';